# What's the rails way to check if a model instance is in an array of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

something like `@users.include? @user` maybe

Answer (score 0):

Yup :) is that not working? include? is definitely the best way to test for array inclusion

Answer (score 0):

If the model instance is the same instance as the one in the array, include? should work:

```
@users.include?(@user)
```

Otherwise, you can do a comparison in a collect loop. For example:

```
@users.detect { |u| u.id == @user.id }
```

In most cases though, .include? is your best bet and should give you the desired result.

Comment: @users.detect {|u| u.id == @user.id} would be a WAY more efficient way of doing your second solution.

Comment: @MattBriggs Updated the answer to use your suggestion. Better late than never. :p